# AfterEach and BeforeEach only for describe()s

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I have this demo code.

```
describe('demo', () => {
      beforeEach( async () => {
        console.log('->before each')
      })

      afterEach( async () => {
        console.log('->after each')
      })

      describe('->1', () => {
        it('->1.1', async () => {
            console.log('->1.1')
        })

        it('->1.2', async () => {
          console.log('->1.2')
        })
      })

      describe('->2', () => {
        it('->2.1', async () => {
            console.log('->2.1')
        })

        it('->2.2', async () => {
          console.log('->2.2')
        })
      })
})
```

And i'm waiting this result:

```
->before each
->1
    ->1.1
    ->1.2
->after each
->before each
->2
    ->2.1
    ->2.2
->after each
```

I want afterEach and beforeEach to run only before and after describe()s, not it()s.

How actually works:

```
->1
    ->before each
    ->1.1
    ->after each
    ->before each
    ->1.2
    ->after each

->2
    ->before each
    ->2.1
    ->after each
    ->before each
    ->2.2
    ->after each
```

I thought afterEach and beforeEach runs only on same level, not in cildren.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes unfortunately `beforeEach()` and `afterEach()` run for every `it()` block. But you could restructure your tests by using `beforeAll()` and `afterAll()` as follows:

```
describe('demo', () => {

  describe('->1', () => {
    beforeAll(async () => {
      console.log('beforeAll');
    });

    afterAll(async () => {
      console.log('afterAll');
    });

    it('->1.1', async () => {
      console.log('->1.1');
    });

    it('->1.2', async () => {
      console.log('->1.2');
    });
  });

  describe('->2', () => {
    beforeAll(async () => {
      console.log('beforeAll');
    });

    afterAll(async () => {
      console.log('afterAll');
    });
    it('->2.1', async () => {
      console.log('->2.1');
    });

    it('->2.2', async () => {
      console.log('->2.2');
    });
  });
});
```

output

```
->beforeAll
->1
    ->1.1
    ->1.2
->afterAll
->beforeAll
->2
    ->2.1
    ->2.2
->afterAll
```

This provides you the expected result but you have to write more code. But in tests, it's ok to have some redundant code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need another annotation

```
beforeAll(functionopt, timeoutopt) - execute once before for a describe
afterAll(functionopt, timeoutopt) - execute once after for a describe
```

More details [here](https://jasmine.github.io/api/2.7/global)